# Char array to a String using .NET system?

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, visual-studio-code, system.io.file

How can I store the contents of a char array into a text file in C# with .NET? I have tried

```
char[] characters = VarInput.ToCharArray();
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\leoga\Documents\Projects_Atom\Pad_Wood\WriteText2CharacterArray.txt", characters);
```

but it comes up with an error message saying

> Argument 2: cannot convert from 'char[]' to 'string'
>   [C:\Users\leoga\Documents\Projects_Atom\Pad_Wood\converter.csproj]

I have also tried it with `File.WriteAllLines()` but it still doesn't work. I am using c# and .NET

Comment: What type is `VarInput` ?

Comment: @HenkHolterman VarInput is a text string

Comment: Then `WriteAllText(path, VarInput);`

Comment: Is the `VarInput.ToCharArray()` just for sample purposes and your code is really passed/provided a `char[]` with no way to associate it with the original `string` (or there was no `string` to begin with)?  Or you do have a `string` and were thinking it can only be written to a file as individual `char`s?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What type is `VarInput`?  If it's a string initially, just remove the `ToCharArray()` call and you can write it to a file directly with `File.WriteAllText`.

```
File.WriteAllText(path, VarInput);
```

Once you have a char array, you don't have to convert to a string in order to write to a file. You can also write bytes directly.

```
var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(characters);
File.WriteAllBytes(path, bytes);
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Reason

- Because OP converted the string to an array when there wasn't a need to, you can use it directly.

#### Other way

- code

```
        public void Write(string path)
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
            using (fs)
            {
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
                using (sw)
                {
                    string VarInput = "11111111";
                    char[] characters = VarInput.ToCharArray();
                    sw.Write(characters);
                }
            }
        }
```

- [About doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/)

Comment: It has been updated. Thank you for pointing out.

Answer (score -1):

There should be a built in function to run joins on Arrays, converting to String.

Here's an example of doing this to export an array as a CSV:

```
String result = String.Join(",",arr)
```

If you're looking to just convert to a String without any delimiters, you can do something like this:

```
String result = String.Join("",arr)
```

Comment: Passing an empty string and a `char[]` to `String.Join()` would be the less-efficient alternative to just passing the `char[]` to the [`String(char[])` constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.string.-ctor#System_String__ctor_System_Char___) (i.e. `String result = new string(arr);`).